# Indexing columns in a csv file

Tags: algorithm, performance, csv, search, indexing

I have a large csv file which each row has different columns, such as ID, username, email, job position, etc.

I want to search for a row by exact matches (username == David), or wildcard (jobPosition == %admin).

I want to index columns in this file to make searches faster, but I don't know which algorithm should I choose (specially for wildcards).

Comment: Do you not have access to a database system you could import it into?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst, This is a self-training project, I just want to learn about wildcard indexing algorithms, I wrote 2 comments that explains it, under btilly's answer.

Answer (score 6):

## How to index a csv file:

To index a csv file you need to read it as a binary file instead of a text file. Use 128, 256 or 512 **block size**. To build the index, you scan your file looking for the beginning of each record and then create an index file like this:

```
  key-value-1, 0, 0
   ........
   ........
  key-value-n, block, offset
```

**key-value** is the value of the key you are indexing on. Can be a composite key. **block** is the block number the record starts at (*be aware that your records can span more than one block*), and **offset** is a number between **0** and **block-size-1** which is the offset into that block. To retrieve your record you look up the key on the index file (using perhaps [**binary search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)) and then use the block-offset to access your record [**directly**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access#Direct_access).

You can also create multiple index files at the same time if you need to search for different criteria.

If you have `CR-LF` as end of line marker be aware that the `CR`can be at the exact end of the block while `LF` will be at the very beginning of the next. You need to be aware of some special cases like these. Once you have created this index file (or files) you can sort it by the key and you are good to go.

Alternatively, if your software allows *fast memory block moving* (like C++ **[memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/)**), you can use **[insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) in combination with binary search**. That way, after you finish building your index(es) they are already sorted. This is particularly efficient if the index entries are being added from a file that is being captured using a slow input device (eg. **keyboard**). If you are managing large amounts of records consider using a [**B-Tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) structure for your index(es).

This schema, allows your csv *database* to accept record **additions**, **deletions** and **updates**. **Additions** are made at the end of the file. To **delete a record**, just change the first character of the record with a unique character like `0x0` and of course delete the entry from the index file. **Updates** can be achieved by deleting and then adding the updated record at the end of the file.

This will create some need for [**garbage collection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) on your *database* but most [**DBMS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_management_system), if not all, do so. Periodically rebuild your index and get rid of the deleted records.

**NOTE:** For a code implementation [**look at this answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899880/how-can-i-split-csv-files-in-python/65189049#65189049) Indexing a 9 Gb csv file of 6867839 lines took about 6 minutes. Joblib is quite slow to store the index on disk. The index file was 134 Mb.

Let's use a toy csv example. We will index the file by record number. For the sake of the example we will store the record number in the key part of the index although this is clearly unnecessary.

```
strings,numbers,colors
string1,1,blue
string2,2,red
string3,3,green
string4,4,yellow
```

The index file will be stored on the list **idx**:

```
 idx

 [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 24], [2, 0, 40], [3, 0, 55], [4, 0, 72], [5, 0, -1]]
```

Note the -1 at the last index element to indicate end of index file in case of a sequential access. You can use a code like this to access any individual row of the csv file **by record number**:

```
def get_rec(n=1,binary=False):
    n=1 if n<0 else n+1
    s=b'' if binary else '' 
    if len(idx)==0:return ''
    if idx[n-1][2]==-1:return ''
    f.seek(idx[n-1][1]*BLKSIZE+idx[n-1][2])
    buff=f.read(BLKSIZE)
    x=buff.find(b'\r')
    while x==-1:
        s=s+buff if binary else s+buff.decode()
        buff=f.read(BLKSIZE)
        x=buff.find(b'\r')
    return s+buff[:x]+b'\r\n' if binary else s+buff[:x].decode()
```

Comment: Nice answer. Could you clarify what do you mean with "insertion sort" ? Why having a different end-of-line character would help ? Let's say you have a CSV that only gets inserts (no updates or deletes), in order to update the index you need to load it to memory, insert the new values and write it back to a file, right ?

Comment: Absolutely. For small files the index can be kept in memory all the time and only being written to disk at the end of the job. For large index files you need to manage the index files using a B-Tree schema or similar. B-Tree implements a page schema and writes the "dirty" pages to disk when necessary so you don't need the whole index file loaded in memory. You may find more about insertion sort [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Answer (score 4):

Short version.  Load the CSV into SQLite, and then query that.  You can learn about SQLite at https://www.sqlite.org/, but I would suggest looking for a library in your language that already has it.

Long version.

Before you get done figuring out how to write your code, you can load the data into SQLite, index it, query it, and be done.  This is even true if you do not currently know how to write SQL.  (Trust me, I know the algorithms you need, and learning them is harder than learning SQL.)

Before you're done actually writing the code your alternate self will have done several other projects.

After you write the code, then you get to debug it.  I guarantee you won't successfully debug it.  Meanwhile in the alternate universe you've continued building more projects.

Once you've debugged your code and put it into production (with unknown bugs still there), you have the win of skipping the initial loading step.  Meanwhile your alternate universe self doesn't even have to think about the fact that SQLite was implemented in very efficient C, with an optimizer that may not match a "real" database, but is better than anything you can roll on your own.

Given this, you really should consider using SQLite.

PS: https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html explains how to do the wildcard match in SQLite.

Comment: In general I agree and love SQLite, but specifically I have done this in the past and found that under some circumstances the imports could take several tens of minutes - it was topping out at about 30 inserts / sec from the CSV input, on modern SSD hardware. So it's a great starting point (and I'll try and get that faster next time I need that project) but not always a viable option.

Comment: @eftpotrm I find "30 inserts / sec" astonishingly low.  I would immediately suspect that the problem is some combination of triggers, indexes and foreign keys.  Did you do the standard load data and THEN create indexes rather than trying to load it with indexes present?

Comment: I agree, it surprised me! Very minimal DB, certainly no triggers - can't speak for keys & indexes off the top of my head. I'll investigate optimisation next time I need it because I certainly like SQLite as a solution (and think it's likely the right one for the OP), but I would watch out for performance.

Comment: Did you try the .import command?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697004/bulk-load-data-into-sqlite for more.

Comment: Thank you btilly for the answer and your time, I've programmed for half of my age, and I'm pretty familiar with SQL and NoSQL databases, actually I worked with MySQL, MS SQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Radis, Memcached and a bunch more, and played with different ORMs ;)... Actually, The file is imported into MySQL, but what I'm asking here is for a self-training project. I Always used database indexes, but never played with a indexing algorithm to learn how they are written and how they work internally. Also, I'm not good in such algorithms and I'm really interested to learn them.

Comment: I think hash tables are not good (because of large amount of data - O(1) ), and btree is the way to go. But my question is that how to play with wildcards. I mean, how can I efficiently index and search for something like "%ad%min%" in large number of rows.

Comment: Ah.  Well, that gets complicated.  For generic use cases, a btree is best.  But for full text scanning, you can store data in a trie.  Then '%ad%min%' could be searched for either by scanning the rows that have "min" in them, or else by creating a list of rows with "ad", intersecting that with a list that have "min", and then scanning the intersection to find things that actually match "%ad%min%".

Be warned that the index will not be small...

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a solution involving SQLite, but how to index a csv file. Either you know how to do it or you don't. Steering the OP away by discouraging him to find a solution is not the right thing to do, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @agcala Usually with an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) it is better to solve the real problem, not the asked for one.  When it became clear that it was meant as a training exercise, I gave a set of keywords to search for.  How to solve this particular problem properly, well, entire courses are taught on that and years have been sunk into freely available precanned solutions.